# How to join strings in two lists and then seperate the strings from the list?

Tags: python, string, list

In the game below, I want to print 3. followed by each number the player has got right in the next try. How can I manage it?

```
#pi memory game  
from sys import exit 
pi = '3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058209749445923078164062862089986280348253421170679'
x = (pi.split('.'))[1] 
right_ans = [] 
print (x) 
turns = 0  
while turns <= 3:   
    i = 0   
    while i<len(x):
        u = input("3.?")
        if u == x[i]:
            right_ans.append(x[i])
            print ("right")
            i +=1 
        else:
            turns += 1
            print ("Turns remain: ", (3-turns))
        if turns == 3:
            print ("Your guesses are over!! You managed %d digits after 3" % len(right_ans))
            exit(0)
```

Comment: Please indent your code. This is python ;-)

Comment: Thanks! I'm new to this so formatting got a little out of place.

Comment: can you suggest me anything I can do?

Answer (score 0):

Here are the things that were wrong in your code and my proposals to fix it :-)

> 1- **Strings are already lists**. You can loop over characters 1 by 1 without `split()`:

```
for x in '3.1415...':
```

> 2- **Favour `raw_input()` over `input()`**. Depending on your version of python, `input()` casts the input value to string or int. **This always fails**:

```
'1' == input()
```

> 3- To minimize risk of infinite loops, always prefer `for loops` over
>   `while loops` when you can

Finally,

> 4- For the sake of **simplicity**, decrement counters and check when they
>   reach `0`, rather than using magic value all along your code (`turns`
>   here)

Here is my proposal of a working game:

```
#pi memory game  
from sys import exit 
pi = '3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058209749445923078164062862089986280348253421170679'
right_ans = [] 
turns = 3
for x in pi[2:]:
    while turns > 0:
        print ("you have to guess:",x,type(x))
        u = raw_input() #Preferred to input(), so 'u' is a string
        print ("you have typed:",u,type(u))
        if u == x:
            right_ans.append(x)
            print ("right")
            break
        turns -= 1
        print ("Turns remain: ", turns)

if turns == 0:
    print ("Your guesses are over!! You managed %d digits after 3" % len(right_ans))
else:
    print ("Good job! You guessed all %d digits after 3" % len(right_ans))
```